# Fetch data from Json stringified string using postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

How can I fetch values from the below json stringified string using a postgres query ? I am using regex to do this but I am trying to write something more generic/simple/trustable query. Yes, I don't trust what I wrote I'm pretty sure what I have will break.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
trim(both '" 'FROM replace(regexp_replace('phone_data', '[\\]
{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'gpslogs' -> 0 ->> 'cataract'
FROM
  "JSON"
WHERE
  "ID" = 'eb7613c6-e7aa-4b46-984e-ebf334293fdb';
```

This is the how the data looks like:

```
   {
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Appreciate your help and suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manipulate JSON with regexes in PostgreSQL. [Postgres has plenty of JSON functions for searching and manipulating JSON data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). What are you trying to get from that JSON?

Comment: let's say in this example, I want the altitude field

Comment: @Schwern also did you notice the extra pair of double quotes in the beginning and the ending

Comment: Sorry, I can't make heads or tails of that mess. I had to clean it up and run it through a reformatter. https://gist.github.com/schwern/933958647c284ba463b51835fe26d57c The problem is you're still thinking of the JSON as a string. It isn't. The B in JSONB is binary. What you see is a string representation with all sorts of messy escaping.

Comment: The question is tagged `jsonb` but is this a JSONB column or a TEXT column?

Comment: Can you enable `plv8` extension as so: `CREATE EXTENSION plv8;` in your DB?

Comment: @Schwern It is a jsonb column

Comment: @KristoMägi I'm not sure I will be allowed to do that.

Comment: Wait, in your DB the actual data type is `jsonb`? Then how do you end up with stringified JSON in the first place? Postgres does not allow to store stringified json into jsonb data type.

Comment: So, the column itself is jsonb, in which we recieve a lot of json data, this is just a part of it which is stringified twice

Comment: Also, for that deep path it is more performant to use `#>` operator, not down the road `.. -> .. ->..`, especially with big JSONs.

Comment: @KristoMägi yep, true that! For nested paths it's better to use #> . Thanks I'll modify.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have double-encoded JSON data. All the real JSON appears to be smashed into one big string value that you then have to unencode, parse as JSON (defeating the point of JSONB), and then search.

Rule of thumb is to not try and work with garbage data. Instead, fix it up and then work with the resulting clean data. This makes everything faster, less buggy, use less memory, and saves a lot of programming time.

This means doing a single `update` to fix the JSON data. Be sure to have transactions on when doing this so you can rollback if you make a mistake. And you'll have to change your importer to also fix the incoming data before inserting it. Finally, there may be other queries which assume the JSON is malformed, they will have to be changed to work with sensible JSON.

Then you can query the JSONB column normally.

```
select phone_device_data->'objects'->0->'data'->'gps_location_logs'->0->>'latitude'
from json_storage
where id = 'eb7613c6-e7aa-4b46-984e-ebf334293fdb';
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work for me. Did you remove the extra quotes and try this ?

Comment: @Anusha If that value you posted with all its weird escapes is what's in the `phone_device_data` column, then something is very, very, very wrong with your data. You posted invalid JSON, and a JSONB field cannot contain invalid JSON. I suspect either `phone_device_data` is not actually JSONB, or its just one big string field with escaped gibberish in it, or you posted something that's not the real value (ie. filtered through some GUI or program). Maybe paste `select phone_device_data from json_storage where id = 'eb7613c6-e7aa-4b46-984e-ebf334293fdb'` somewhere.

Comment: believe me that is how it is. Which is why I was used regex.

Comment: @Anusha In that case, fix the data. Run one `update` to remove the extra quoting and escaping and make it sensible JSON. And change your importer to fix any new data before its inserted. Then you (and everybody else) can write sane `select` statements. Rather than trying to work around the problems in the data, fix the data. It defeats the point of JSONB to have all the JSON locked up in a string value.

Comment: This is how we receive it, there is nothing I can do to fix the data. Now all I can do is fetch the values.

Comment: @Anusha Of course you can. You can run an `update` to fix the data stored in your database.

Comment: how ? what update ? as in remove the extra quotes you are saying ?

Comment: @Anusha Yes. Instead of doing `trim(both '" 'FROM replace(regexp_replace('phone_device_data', '[\\]
{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))` on every query, do it once in an update. Something like `update from json_storage set phone_device_data = ...all that mess...`. Then `phone_device_data` contains sensible JSON. ***Be sure to have transactions on before trying this so you can rollback if you make a mistake***

Comment: @Anusha Note: There might be other queries which also assume the data is malformated. You'll have to find and fix those.

Comment: hmm, I think that makes sense!